# How can I change PDF title in broswer view(Data from Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring

I want visit my program and get a pdf data show in broswer such like this:
[image]

but you can see the Upper left corner is my view path,not my filename, how can i change it?

the src is as follow:

```
    @GetMapping("/getPDF")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF() throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
        String filename = "测试.pdf";

        File file = new File("E:\\2018版计信本科人才培养方案总2019.11.15（适用于2018级及以后年级）(1).pdf");

        headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(filename,"UTF-8"));

        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done it!

you can use some tools like pdfbox and using stream to output

core src as follow:

```
        File file = new File(pathPlace);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new MyException(ResultEnum.FILE_EXIST);
        }

        String fileName = saveFileDirectoryMapper.getFileNameById(fileId);

        response.setHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));

        try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
             // load pdf
             PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file)) {
            // get document attribute
            PDDocumentInformation info = document.getDocumentInformation();

            // change title
            info.setTitle(fileName);
            document.setDocumentInformation(info);
            // output data to stream
            document.save(out);
        }
```